# How to have a Angular Material dropdown populated with icons instead of text

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-material2

I have a Template Driven Form and I want one of the dropdowns to have a font awesome icon list to appear but I am not able to do so.

Something like:

[image]

[image]

I am using Template Driven forms and Angular Material beta version using md instead of mat components.

This is what I tried untill now:

```html
<md-select placeholder="Icon" [(ngModel)]="actionHook.icon" name = "icon">
  <md-option *ngFor="let icon of icons" [value]="icon.value">
    <img class="fa-address-book"/>
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

But it dosent show up, Even if I cannot get it in a nested form. How to get it in a single dropdown with all icons where the value is class name and the display is the icon image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img>` tag needs src attribute in order to work:

```
<img with="10" height="10" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg">
```

If you wish to use fontawesome classes then use `<i>` or ' tags:

```
...
    <i class="fa-address-book"></i>
...
```

or

```
...
    <span class="fa-address-book"></span>
...
```

[**Here**](https://embed.plnkr.co/QHV62RN51R4RxTsdQZMB/) is a working demo with **md** prefixes

Comment: anchor tag dosn't work in md-option already tried it , i was trying to use font awesome unicode that too fails

Comment: then use img with src tag?

Comment: i have to use font awsome and i cannot have images to use here is there a way i can get the class names and use it

Comment: I don't see why <i> tag is an anchor tag.